# Git with autocrlf=true checks out files with mixed line endings as-is

Tags: git, newline, msysgit, line-endings, core.autocrlf

So, I always thought that with `core.autocrlf=true` Git replaces all `LF` endings with `CRLF` when checking out the file into the working directory.

From the [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration):

> If you’re on a Windows machine, set it to true – this converts LF endings into CRLF when you check out code

However, when checking out a file with mixed line endings and `core.autocrlf` set to `true`, my version of Git checks out the file as-is.

I've found a very convenient GitHub repository to test this behaviour - https://github.com/YueLinHo/TestAutoCrlf

Test results:

- A file with `LF` endings only (LF.txt)

  - With `autocrlf=false`: checked out as-is (all line endings are `LF`)
  - With `autocrlf=true`: all line endings are changed to `CRLF` on checkout

So far so good, everything as I expected. Now for the file with mixed line endings:

- A file with mixed line endings (MIX-more_CRLF.txt, MIX-more_LF.txt)

  - With `autocrlf=false`: checked out as-is (a mix of `LF` and `CRLF`)
  - With `autocrlf=true`: checked out as-is (a mix of `LF` and `CRLF`)

Why does this happen? I haven't seen anything about `autocrlf=true` not touching files with mixed line endings.

Are my Git settings at fault? I checked the `core.autocrlf` setting running `git config --get core.autocrlf` in the repository folder after checking out with `autocrlf=true` in the global .gitconfig, and the command returned true. There is no .gitattributes file to overwrite the settings.

All tests were made on Git version `1.9.5.msysgit.0`.

**EDIT:** Same behaviour on the latest msysgit version `1.9.5.msysgit.1`.

My original problem is that I somehow managed to commit a mixed-line ending file with only `LF` endings while having `core.autocrlf` set to `true`, meaning the file was checked out as-is, but commited with `CRLF` changed to `LF`. I'm currently working from another machine and cannot reproduce this behaviour on my msysgit version.

Comment: It actually sounds like a good default; if a file has mixed line-endings, then there probably is a good reason for that in general situations. The obvious solution is to convert the file to the system default line-endings and then commit it, allowing git to convert the line-endings.

Comment: @MicroVirus Maybe it's a good default, but I haven't seen this behaviour documented anywhere, so I was wondering why it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am reposting an answer that was deleted by its owner, because I think it gives the best explanation. I have no idea why the author deleted it, I think it's correct and I've voted to undelete.

Apparently this behavior is hardcoded in Git and does not depend on core.safecrlf (and I've tested this, mixed files are left untouched even if I set `git config core.safecrlf false`.

Original answer follows:

---

Autocrlf **doesn't** convert mixed line endings, as the git's source code tells:

https://github.com/git/git/commit/a0ad53c18100226cb1a138cb9b3bc3615170be8f

Note the comments here:

> ```
> /* No "naked" LF? Nothing to convert, regardless. */
> ```

and

> ```
> /* If we have any CR or CRLF line endings, we do not touch it */
> /* This is the new safer autocrlf-handling */
> ```

Mixed line endings conversion is non-reversible, when it's done, Git crashed.

So, if you wanna convert your files' line endings automatically, it might be a good idea to set a [.gitattributes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) file dealing with end-of-line.
Such as:

```
LF.txt eol=lf
CRLF.txt eol=crlf
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the value of `core.safecrlf` ?

If `core.safecrlf` is set to `true`, then mixed line endings files will not be converted. (Because the converting is not reversible if line endings is mixed)

Comment: `git config --get core.safecrlf` in the repository folder returns an empty line, so I guess it's not set.

Comment: So maybe it's default value is true.

Comment: But `core.safecrlf=true` wouldn't let me commit a file with mixed line endings if any conversions take place. `warn` would notify me. Instead, I get no message whatsoever on such a commit, even if I explicitly set `core.safecrlf` to `true`.

Comment: @MicroVirus Yes that's it.