# eol=crlf doesn't affect a .cs file

Tags: git, eol, gitattributes

git v2.30.2.1
I have a checked-in C# file that contains a mix of LF and CRLF line endings. So I checked in a .gitattributes file to the repo containing:

```
* text=auto eol=crlf
```

But when I check out the branch the C# file does not get converted to CRLF. In Notepad++ I can see the mixed line endings. This returns false for that file:

```
File.ReadAllText(fullPath).Any(c => c == '\0');
```

So I don't think git would have any reason to treat it as binary. What else could be preventing the file from being converted to CRLF?

As an experiment, I checked in a dummy.cs file containing all LF endings. When I check the branch out, that file gets converted to CRLF. So it seems the .gitattributes is functioning for some files.

Comment: TL;DR Git won't convert files with mixed endings. https://stackoverflow.com/q/29793339/3216427 And the reason is, that's not a safe operation, since it's not reversible. Files with mixed endings are often not actually text files, so that's a pretty good safeguard imho. You'll just have to manually clean up the line endings in that file and commit that, then things will work as you want.

Comment: @joanis Yes! Please post it as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: And @JimC the credit is really due on the duplicate question and its answers. Upvote the answer there that helped you instead.